# Firebase Storage error in Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I use `const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();` in the cloud function, and at the very top, I have:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
```

When I try to deploy, it gives me an error:

> i  functions: Loaded environment variables from. Error: Missing bucket name. If you are unit testing, please provide a bucket name through functions.storage.bucket(bucketName), or set process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG.`

This only started happening after I updated, I believe. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm also having this issue, but I have not changed anything or updated `firebase-functions`. This is happening before I run `admin.initializeApp()`.

Comment: Same error message when trying to deploy cloud functions. Just started occurring after updating firebase-tools to 9.16.2

Comment: I updated firebase-functions `npm install --save firebase-functions@latest` and it seems to work now.

Comment: Seems to be fixed now without changes to my dependencies -- must have been a backend firebase issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google released new firebase-tools with a bug, just fixed the bug at v9.16.3
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v9.16.3

[Release note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3owWC.png)

Answer (score 0):

After some more testing, I realized that the issue was not with `admin.storage().bucket()`, it was with `functions.storage.object().onFinalize(...` which should be `functions.storage.bucket('{bucketname}').object().onFinalize(...` instead.

Comment: I am experiencing the same error and tried specifying the bucket name as `functions.storage.bucket('project-id.appspot.com').onFinalize(...` but it still complained that the bucket name wasn't specified. I'm just using the default bucket and this was working up through yesterday... Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure. What I did was started from scratch and manually added one function at a time to try and find the issue. Maybe you can try that and that can help you isolate why the error occurs.